# jsdoc with node generates empty index.html

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I used the following command to generate html from the javascript file.

```
$> jsdoc --debug jquery.js 
$> open out/index.html
```

*Output of the command*

```
DEBUG: JSDoc 3.3.2 (Sat, 13 Jun 2015 22:20:28 GMT)
DEBUG: Environment info: {"env":{"conf":{"tags":{"allowUnknownTags":true,"dictionaries":["jsdoc","closure"]},"templates":{"monospaceLinks":false,"cleverLinks":true},"source":{"includePattern":".+\\.js(doc)?$","excludePattern":"(^|\\/|\\\\)_"},"plugins":[]},"opts":{"_":["jquery.js"],"configure":"conf.json","debug":true,"destination":"./out/","encoding":"utf8"}}}
DEBUG: Parsing source files: ["/Users/darpandagha/jquery.js"]
Parsing /Users/darpandagha/jquery.js ...complete.
DEBUG: Finished parsing source files.
DEBUG: Indexing doclets...
DEBUG: Adding inherited symbols, mixins, and interface implementations...
DEBUG: Adding borrowed doclets...
DEBUG: Post-processing complete.
Generating output files...complete.
Finished running in 2.76 seconds.
```

Answer (score 11):

On the last jsdoc version you can specify the index content by using "-R README.md" on command line and putting what you want in this file.
I found this in [DocStrap documentation](https://github.com/docstrap/docstrap).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10664633)

Comment: The first sentence describe how to resolve the problem. Why do you see it as "link-only answer"?